# Silverlight Usercontrol clr namespace

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I'm building a silverlight MVVM app (using the GalaSoft MVVM light template). The app has some UserControls. Now I have stumbeld across somthing which seems like a namespace issue. The namespaces are defined in this way:

```
MyApp.Controls
-> my user controls 
MyApp.View
-> different pages of the app (which use the user controls)
MyApp
-> the namespace of the main page (root namespace)
```

This works ok as long as I don't give any of the UserControls an **x:Name**. As soon as an **x:Name** is defined, the build breaks with the following message:

```
error CS0426: The type name 'Controls' does not exist in the type 'MyApp.MyApp'
```

That is realy strange! I can resolve this issue by changing the namespace **MyApp.Controls** to **MyAppControls** or by manipulating the generated code, so that the direct reference **MyApp.Controls.MyControl** is replaced with **using MyApp.Controls** and then instanciate the control with **MyControl** (however this will be overwritten again, as soon as I switch to the desgin view).

Does anyone know the reason for this strange behaviour? I would have expected that this is a very common problem?

Comment: can you attach a sample code?

Comment: sorry, the project is quite complex. I've tried to simplify it, but then the problem disapeard. So there must be something I have overlooked :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the reason: I also had a resource file with the name MyApp. This led to the generation of a class MyApp and therefore the compiler got confused between the class MyApp and the namespace MyApp. I have renamed the Resource file to something different and now the project compiles again.